# Помогите с preg_replace, нужно заменить ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть переменная `$text`. В ней находится HTML код.

Надо найти ссылки вида `<a href="http://$_GET["s"]/next-lvl/next-lvl2/">любой текст</a>` и заменить в них подстроку `$_GET["s"]` на `test.ru/?s=$_GET["s"]`.

Comment: Не совсем понял.. нужно всего лишь `test.ru/?s=` вставить перед гетом? Если да, то почему бы не  написать `str_replace('http://', 'http://test.ru/?s=', $text)`  или `preg_replace('/(http:\/\/)/g', 'http://test.ru/?s=', $text)`

Comment: А `$_GET["s"]` это какая-то известная на момент выполнения регулярного выражения строка?

Comment: Ну давайте `$key = $_GET["s"];`, а суть в том, что заменить ссылки не просто http://, а именно `<a href=""></a>`, при том, что оставить конец ссылки.

Comment: Все равно не понял) Попробуйте описать более яснее что на входе и что на выходе. Можно также подправить вопрос.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в php есть функция экранирования строки под регулярное выражение?

Comment: @user5419467, путь `/next-lvl/next-lvl2/` является фиксированным? Или может быть любым?

Answer (score 1):

Вашу задачу можно решить, например, так:

```
// Исходный текст
$text = '<a href="http://example.com/next-lvl/next-lvl2/">любой текст</a>';

// Вместо "example.com" вы можете использовать содержимое переменной $_GET['s']
$domain = preg_quote('example.com', '/');

$res = preg_replace(
    '/(<a\s+href="http:\/\/)(' . $domain . '\/next-lvl\/next-lvl2\/"\s*>.*?<\/a>)/',
    '$1test.ru/?s=$2',
    $text
);

// Использовать полученный результат можно по разному ;)
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Какие-то навороченные манипуляции)) Не проще использовать то, что я описал в комментарии? Намного проще, а итог такой же.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не проще по двум причинам: 1. по-мимо ссылок в разметке может использовать просто URL. 2. Вы не накладываете ограничений на путь от корня домена (`/next-lvl/next-lvl2/`)

Comment: В задаче такого и не стояло. В прочем, поэтому я и попросил более подробно написать задачу, чтоб было понятно точно что нужно человеку

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, п1. был указан в задаче явным образом, так, что ваш путь все равно не подходит. Насчет конкретизации вопроса, в целом согласен, но комментарии кое-что поясняют.